# My form doesn submit with Jquery Validate + Rails Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-validate

I have a form that submits correctly without jquery validate, but does not with jquery validate.  Using jquery validate, it correctly shows when the field has less than 6 characters, and the error goes away when it is 6+.  However, clicking on the button does nothing.    The validate script is:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    alert("document ready");
    $("#new_hotel").validate({
        debug: true,
            rules: {
                "hotel[name]": {required: true, minlength: 6},
                    }
                            });
        });
```

My form is this:

```
<div class="modal-body">

<%= form_for @hotel do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name%>

  <div class="modal-footer">
   <a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</a>
 <%=  f.submit 'Create Hotel' , :class => 'btn btn-primary', :type => 'submit' %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you give us a URL to see this?

Comment: Sorry, but it is still in development and I put it on the web yet.

Comment: Ok, I didn't have a submit handler in my javascript.  The correct code is:

    $(document).ready(function () {
 alert("document ready");
  $("#new_hotel").validate({
   debug: true,
    rules: {
     "hotel[name]": {required: true, minlength: 6},

     },
        
  submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
    });
});